# Error preaparing registered callable parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a java project that uses JPA repository for connecting to MySql database.

Below you see my stored procedure in the database and my sp works correctly I called it in DataGrip.

```
create procedure GetDataComments(IN pageIndex int, IN pageSize int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE startPoint INT;
    SET startPoint = ((pageIndex-1) * pageSize);

    SELECT
       *
    FROM store_db.comment AS C
    WHERE C.blog_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY C.id
    LIMIT pageSize OFFSET startPoint;
END;
```

This is my repository in my java program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends 
JpaRepository<CommentEntity, Long> {
   @Procedure(procedureName = "GetDataComments")
   ArrayList<CommentEntity> GetData(@Param("pageIndex") int pageIndex, @Param("pageSize") int pageSize);
}
```

and this is the error that I get.

```
detailMessage = "Error preparing registered callable parameter"
sqlException = (SQLExeption@9714) "java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index 3 is out of ranger (1, 2)"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures#query-annotation

Comment: @Andreas If you see all I've done is exactly like the tutorial.

Comment: Really? `@Procedure(procedureName = "GetDataComments")` is *exactly* like `@Query(value = "CALL GetDataComments(:pageIndex, :pageSize);", nativeQuery = true)`? Guess I need to get my eyes adjusted, because they don't look anything alike to me.

Comment: @Andreas my English is weak, I didn't want to disrespect.

Comment: @Andreas yes there is two option one is use Query and another option is Procedure on that page is referenced both of them.
I don't want to use a query because I have a procedure and it's risky to use queries.

Comment: But the examples using `@Procedure` are returning a *value* using an `OUT` parameter, and the example using `@Query` is returned a **result set** without using an `OUT` parameter. Let's see, which of those two scenarios fits your procedure ... Right, the `@Query` version does. You know, **query**, as in it returns a result set with the data. --- Why did you bother to ask for help here if you refuse to listen to the advice we're giving you?

Comment: @Andreas I'm new in java world but I have a good experience in asp.net and you know how I learnt it, I searched and searched and I didn't satisfied with the first answer because I always search for the best solution. Thank god my colleague were enthusiasm to discuss about issues that I was learning.